# Lazily create dask dataframe from generator

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I want to lazily create a Dask dataframe from a generator, which looks something like:

```
[parser.read(local_file_name) for local_file_name in repo.download_files())]
```

Where both parser.read and repo.download_files return generators (using yield). parser.read yields a dictionary of key-value pairs, which (if I was just using plain pandas) would collect each dictionary in to a list, and then use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
```

What's the best way to create a dask dataframe from this? The reason is that a) I don't know necessarily the number of results returned, and b) I don't know the memory allocation of the machine that it will be deployed on.

Alternatively what should I be doing differently (e.g. maybe create a bunch of dataframes and then put those in to dask instead?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the single-machine Dask scheduler then you'll need to know how many files you have to begin with.  This might be something like the following:

```
filenames = repo.download_files()
dataframes = [delayed(load)(filename) for filename in filenames]
df = dd.from_delayed(dataframes)
```

If you use the [distributed scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can add new computations on the fly, but this is a bit more advanced.